# php force download on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, download

I have i a php script which working fine on windows to force download file from external link file. I mean download on my computer and read the donwloaded file well done
But in my ubuntu the same code download but for reading it's a big problem .I have the folloing error with "eye of gnome" :=Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x3c 0x70) =
Maybe i have to change headers i think so buttt... any idea will welcome thx

```
// required for IE, otherwise Content-disposition is ignored    
if (ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
            ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

// addition by Jorg Weske
        //$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename, "."), 1));
        header("Pragma: public"); // required
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private", false); // required for certain browsers
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download; name=\"$filename\"");
// change, added quotes to allow spaces in filenames, by Rajkumar Singh
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\";");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
//header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
        readfile("$filename");
        exit();
```

Comment: Look into the JPEG file: Chances are there's a PHP error breaking the data stream.

Comment: And what *does* the downloaded file have? Try `file`.

Comment: `application/force-download` is invalid, as well as the `name=` parameter there. Just leave it. And you already have the proper `Content-Disposition:` header anyway.

Comment: I'd suggest that you look at the contents of `$filename` first. Depending on where you get that from, it could be that you're trying to use a Windows filename (including drive letters) on Linux which will of course not work - since you mention it did work on Windows. Logging PHP errors using `log_errors`, `error_log` and `error_reporting` in php.ini could be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

`0x3c 0x70` = `<P`. Are you sure your PHP script is not sending any HTML before the JPEG data? The script may also generate a warning or notice that gets sent before the JPEG data.